# Azure web app - "HttpClient Unable to connect to the remote server"

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to make a request using `HttpClient` in my azure web app but I get the error: `Unable to connect to the remote server`

If I open the kudu console I can successfully make the request using:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://mydomain/myendpoint
```

When I run the program locally it works.

When I run the program inside an azure web app it does not work.

```
HttpClient _client;        

public MyHttpClient() {
  _client = new HttpClient();
  _client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyUri"]);          
  _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();            
  _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));        }

//...

  var path = "/myendpoint";
  var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();        
  data.Add("param1", value);        
  var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(path, data);
```

**Update 1:**

I tried setting:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | 
SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

but it had no effect.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient

Comment: I think the issue is mostly because of TLS protocol. You may need to explicitly set this before making "PostAsJsonAsync" call. Check the link provided by @LocEngineer

Answer (score 2):

You can not make direct call to your on=premise service from Azure Web App. You need Hybrid Connection Manager for this purpose. Look at below post:

[Azure web app service to call onpremise WEB API using HttpClient using hybrid connection manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020261/azure-web-app-service-to-call-onpremise-web-api-using-httpclient-using-hybrid-co/48024208?noredirect=1#comment83052456_48024208)

Comment: I'm getting this:` 'HttpClientHandler' does not contain a definition for 'SslProtocols'`

Comment: Please verify you have this namespace/package added in your project System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0