# Azure Relay Hybrid connection - HTTP protocol vs WebSockets

Tags: azure, http, websocket, azure-hybrid-connections, azure-relay

Using "Azure Relay Hybrid Connection" while sending and receiving messages using the **websocket** protocol, if there is delay in receiving the response no exception occurred.

But when sending and receiving messages to "Azure Relay Hybrid Connection" using **HTTP** protocol and if there is more than 60secs delay in receiving the response, error response received which says *504 Gateway Time-out exception* & exception message says "*The request was routed to the listener but the listener did not respond in the required time*', Why??

Since it is HTTP protocol, it can't be keep the connection open forever like websocket?

In "Azure Relay Hybrid Connection" while using HTTP protocol, by default 'Gateway Time-out' is 60secs, how to extend the default timeout duration?

Timed-out requests can be retried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure web app service to call onpremise WEB API using HttpClient using hybrid connection manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020261/azure-web-app-service-to-call-onpremise-web-api-using-httpclient-using-hybrid-co)

Comment: [Azure Relay Hybrid Connections protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/relay-hybrid-connections-protocol)